# how to use Primary: true with scrollcontroller in the same ScrollView ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to make primary attribute a dynamic value which changes depends on the scroll position but it shows an error because i'm using both of primary and scroll controller , any solution or another idea to use both of them .

my main problem is i have main menu scrolling view and products scrolling view
when i scroll up products scrolling view the main menu scrolling up while im not in the top of products list

what i have tried :

```
CustomScrollView(
primary : isTop,
controller : customscontroller
)
.
.
.
void scrollListner() {
    setState(() {
      if (customscontroller.position.pixels==0.0)
        {
          isTop = true;
        }
      else
        isTop=false;
    });
  }
```